# Eclipse commits not showing up on Git Contributions

Tags: java, git, eclipse, github, git-commit

I am currently going trying to learn java, and my IDE is Eclipse. I connected my Github account and am easily able to push/pull etc. Everything is working great, except for the fact that my commits are not coming up on my Contributions.

I think I have found the issue, but I am not sure what the solution is. If someone can help that would be great, I'm sure it's an easy fix.

Under the "Git Staging" tab on Eclipse, there is a section for 'Author', and 'Committer'.

[image: Eclipse view]
[image: Github commits description]

As I was writing this message I was able to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Under the author & committer section, all you have to do is change it from:

```
name <name@localhost>
```

To:

```
GitHubUsername <GitHubEmail>
```

For a more permenant solution:
[image: Source: https://eclipsesource.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/2.png]

Through this method,  it should automatically change the default Author/Committer to what you enter here.

Go through this article for more information.
https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/egit-tutorial/